# How can I make an X-Y scatter plot with histograms next to the X-Y axes?

Tags: plotting

I just saw a nice plot [there](http://pragcap.com/the-dollarequities-correlation-reversal):

[image]

How could I implement that in Mathematica — by which I mean the plot structure, not so much the styling.

Comment: That's not fair, Mike, I have to get a lot of work done today. :)

Comment: We should both wait for Heike to make something very nice. :)

Comment: @Verbeia you'll recognize the plot as being from Bloomberg. They also have a plot style for line plots with a gradient fill below the line. Has anyone ever implemented that in Mma? I was thinking of posting that as a question.

Comment: Look at my answer: yes, I did recognise it as being from Bloomberg :D. I haven't tried to create a gradient `Filling` before - it's not the sort of thing we do at my employer. We are quite minimalist on the decoration side.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's my solution, which constructs the three components and uses `Inset` to combine them into a single graphic.  I've taken some care so that:

- the coordinate systems should line up across the plots (check the gridlines)
- as many graphics and plotting options are respected without breaking the layout
- the graphic can be reasonable resized

---

```
customPlot[data_, o___] := 
 Block[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, x, y, mainplot, xhist, yhist, 
   opts = Flatten[{o}]},
  {x, y} = Transpose[data];
  xhist = HistogramList[x, 50];
  yhist = HistogramList[y, 50];
  {xmin, xmax} = Through[{Min, Max}[First[xhist]]];
  {ymin, ymax} = Through[{Min, Max}[First[yhist]]];
  mainplot = 
   ListPlot[data, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, True}}, 
    Axes -> False, FrameTicks -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.02], ImagePadding -> {{None, 1}, {None, 1}},
    FilterRules[opts, Options[ListPlot]], 
    FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3], GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted]];
  xhist = 
   Histogram[x, {First[xhist]}, 
    Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}},
    FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, Axes -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/3, ImagePadding -> {{1, 1}, {None, All}},
    FilterRules[opts, Options[Histogram]], 
    GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted]];
  yhist = 
   Histogram[y, {First[yhist]}, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, Axes -> False, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}, AspectRatio -> 3,
    BarOrigin -> Left, ImagePadding -> {{All, None}, {1, 1}},
    FilterRules[opts, Options[Histogram]], 
    GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3], 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted]];
  Graphics[{{Opacity[0], Point[{{360, 360}, {-120, -120}}]},
    Inset[mainplot, {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom}, {360, 360}],
    Inset[xhist, {0, 0}, {Left, Top}, {360, Automatic}],
    Inset[yhist, {0, 0}, {Right, Bottom}, {Automatic, 360}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-120, 360}, {-120, 360}}, 
   FilterRules[opts, Options[Graphics]], 
   ImagePadding -> {{30, 1}, {30, 1}}]
  ]
```

Now to create some data and try it out:

```
d = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, 0.4], 100];

customPlot[d]
```

> [image]

```
customPlot[d, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Orange], 
   ChartStyle -> Orange, ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle", 
   FrameStyle -> White, Background -> Black]
```

> [image]

Comment: nice one Brett. :)

Comment: This can occasionally get misaligned due to the placement of the plot markers.  Try evaluating it many times and you'll get a random dataset that shows this eventually.  Here's an example I got by accident: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M7ulr.png   I really really wish it were easier and less painful to robustly align things in Mathematica ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I just set `ImagePadding` on all the components to fix this (which means that tick labels may get clipped slightly.)

Comment: @BrettChampion Very pretty ;-)

Answer (score 49):

There is also a more eye-catchy approach that uses built-in functions.

```
data = RandomReal[BinormalDistribution[{-1, 2}, {1, 1}, .8], 1000];
GraphicsColumn[
    Table[DensityHistogram[data, {.2}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
    Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> p},
    ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
    LabelStyle -> Bold],
    {p, {True, "Histogram", "SmoothHistogram", "BoxWhisker"}}]]
```

[image: densitiy histograms]

And it works also with `SmoothDensityHistogram`, although it seems that in this case `Histogram` cannot be used as a method:

```
GraphicsColumn[
    Table[SmoothDensityHistogram[data, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
    Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> p},
    ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
    LabelStyle -> Bold],
    {p, {True, "SmoothHistogram", "BoxWhisker"}}]]
```

[image]

---

### Scatterplot with histograms

```
data = RandomReal[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, .8], 1000];
hist = DensityHistogram[data, {.2}, 
    Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}][[1, 2]];
Show[
 Graphics[hist, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], 
     Scaled[0.02]}}],
 ListPlot[data]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you learn about all the options for `Method -> {"DistributionAxes" ->...}` only `"BoxWhisker"` is listed in the examples.

Comment: I stumbled upon an example that used the `Histogram` as a "DistributionAxes" option, so I followed then the trial-and-error method to find other solutions. It might well be that there are other options out there that work.

Comment: Disappointing when users have to guess at these things. they should be documented.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch  The 'What's New' pages have [lots](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/statistical-visualization/show-birds-eye-view-of-2d-data.html) of nice [examples](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/statistical-visualization/annotate-binned-density-histograms-with-marginal-d.html).  Besides, this is *clearly* [documented](http://wolfram.com/xid/0fq6t4kgpp3e6-ddkgnm), at least as much as experimental features are ever documented.  \\[MischievousSmiley]

Comment: @Brett I think all material relevant to a function should be documented at the function page (novel concept??). That is where people look. i.e. if a user wants information about a function should they go to the function page or scroll through the whats new in version 8 page? Seriously! \[ShakngHeadSmiley]

Comment: I was just going through Edward Tufte's book - "A Visual Display of Quantitative Information" and saw this (or something very similar to the first "True" example) applied to a scatter plot... Is there no built-in functionality in ListPlot for this?  Is the easiest way to overlay the scatter plot on the parts pulled from the histogram?

Comment: @MRN16 I don't think there is a built-in functionality in `ListPlot`. If you post a [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), you might get answers from all users.

Comment: This is a very nice feature, but I only learned about it here. I have been using DensityHistogram for years, and I had no idea it could do this. @BrettChampion Indeed, it is in the reference page, but very well hidden. May I suggest adding one such example under Basic Examples, at the very beginning? Ot at least under Scope. Just not in Options -> Method. That's the most obscure option, and it's hidden two levels deep within subsections.

Comment: @VLC is it possible to change the color of the Histogram independently from the color of the 2D plot?

Comment: @Valerio Not that I’m aware of.

Answer (score 19):

This doesn't have the styling and it doesn't yet enforce the plot ranges or implement the regression line, but it's a start:

```
fakeBloombergThing[data:{{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}..}] := 
 Grid[{{Histogram[data[[All, 2]], BarOrigin -> Left , 
     AspectRatio -> 5, ImageSize -> 80], 
    ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     ImageSize -> 350]}, {Null, 
    Histogram[data[[All, 1]] , AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
     ImageSize -> 350]}}]
```

Some fake data:

```
testdata = 
 RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{-1, 1}, {1, 2}, -.6], 100];

fakeBloombergThing[testdata]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd probably add some fixed `ImagePadding` as well for cases where significant figures in ticks can be large. That might also correct the misalignment of the "Y" histogram x axis with the scatter plot x axis.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't finessed that stuff yet. People should feel free to edit this.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a truly hacky approach that uses `Show` to align a `ListPlot` of the points with the `DensityHistogram`, which we use only for the histograms along the axes. In order to hide the actual density histogram, we make everything white (which somewhat limits the styling options).

```
somePoints = RandomReal[BinormalDistribution[{-1, 2}, {1, 1}, .8], 1000];
Show[
 DensityHistogram[somePoints, {.2}, ColorFunction -> (White &),
  Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}],
 ListPlot[somePoints]]
```

[image: the plot]

Comment: You can have more flexibility using `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0] &)` instead of `ColorFunction->(White &)`