# Force Plot Area size to be equal excluding axes

Tags: plotting

I have two plots, both with the exact same formatting (frame, text style, etc.). One of them has 2-digit values for the y axes, the other has scientific notation because the value are large. In addition, they can have a different number of lines for the Axes labels.

I set ImageSize->250, and the bounding boxes of the images (plots) are set to 250 pixels. Cool. Normally this is fine. However, when the two plots have different axes or labels, this results in:

[image: ImageSize->250. Bounding boxes of images are the same]

What I want is the actual plot area to be the same, without manually adjusting ImageSize for the 2nd image:

[image: The Plot areas are the same size, but the bounding box for the entire image is different.]

Notice how the labels make the bounding box grow outward, but the plot area size is the same (also in width, just not shown). In this particular example, the right image has ImageSize->280.

Does anyone know how to set the plot area size rather than the ImageSize?

**EDIT 1:**

@anononononomous mentioned a function to get the max padding size, and then apply it to each plot. This is getting closer! But it's clipping the FrameLabel:

(Also, sorry for adding more data, it doesn't change the question though).

[image: anononononomous's solution]

Comment: I believe `GraphicsGrid` will equalize the heights.

Comment: I think, if you use the same values for the options  `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` in both plots, you should get the same plot area size in both.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Correct, DavidCarraher's solution is not sufficient. kguler, That's getting closer. If you pad the images enough, then you can get the plot area sizes eqaul. However, you end up with a lot of extra space between images (if they're in a list, for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With fingers crossed that someone will come up with a less manual method, I suggest the following completely manual approach: use the same setting for `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` in all the plots to get the plot area sizes equalized.

```
 bwc1 = BoxWhiskerChart[data, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  LabelStyle -> Green, FrameLabel -> {{Style["y axis", Bold, 14, Green], None}, 
  {Style["x axis", Bold, 14, Green], None}},
  ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> {{85, 5}, {50, 5}}];
 bwc2 = BoxWhiskerChart[100 data, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["line 1\nline 2", Bold],
   FrameTicks -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue],
   FrameLabel -> {{Style["y axis", Bold, 14], None}, 
    {Style["y axis", Bold, 14], None}},
   ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> {{85, 5}, {50, 5}}];
 bwc3 = BoxWhiskerChart[100000 data, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["line 1\nline 2\nline 3", Bold, 24],
   FrameTicks -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 16, Red],
   FrameLabel -> {{Style["y axis", Bold, 14], None}, 
      {Style["y axis", Bold, 14], None}},
  ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> {{85, 5}, {50, 5}}];
```

you get the same plot area size for all three plots:

```
 Overlay[{bwc1, bwc2, bwc3}, Alignment -> {Right, Bottom}]
```

[image]

But ... "you end up with a lot of extra space between images":

```
 Grid[{{bwc1, bwc2, bwc3}}, Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

If you wrap each plot in `Framed` and set the `FrameMargins` for each to get rid of the extra spaces on the left:

```
 fbwc1 = Framed[bwc1, FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> {{-50, 0}, {0, 0}}];
 fbwc2 = Framed[bwc2, FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> {{-40, 0}, {0, 0}}];
 fbwc3 = Framed[bwc3, FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}];
```

you get equal plot area sizes:

```
 Overlay[{fbwc1, fbwc2, fbwc3}, Alignment -> {Right, Bottom}]
```

[image]

and no extra spaces on the left:

```
 Grid[{{fbwc1, fbwc2, fbwc3}}, Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice use of negative frame margins

Comment: I'm not sure how you could automate this. It looks like a manual method to me ...but if someone is doing a lot of these they can presumably set up a template once and then use repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's start with some box whisker charts:

```
data = RandomReal[10, {4, 20}];
bwc1 = BoxWhiskerChart[data,
    FrameLabel->{{Style["y axis",14], None}, {Style["x axis", 14], None}}
];
bwc2 = BoxWhiskerChart[100 data,
    FrameLabel->{{Style["y axis",16], None}, {Style["x axis", 26], None}},
    PlotLabel->Style["line 1\nline 2", 14]
];
bwc3 = BoxWhiskerChart[10^5 data, 
    FrameLabel->{{Style["y axis",14], None}, {Style["x axis", 14], None}},
    PlotLabel->Style["line 1\nline 2\nline 3", 24]
];
```

What happens when we try to use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row):

```
Row[{bwc1, bwc2, bwc3}]
```

[image]

Not very good. To fix this, the simplest approach is to use the undocumented syntax `ImageSize -> Automatic -> width`, which sets the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) size to width. Also, include a [`BaselinePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaselinePosition) option so that the axes of each chart are lined up:

```
Row[{
    Show[bwc1, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 200, BaselinePosition -> Axis],
    Show[bwc2, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 200, BaselinePosition -> Axis],
    Show[bwc3, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 200, BaselinePosition -> Axis]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: I love this answer! Adding to it, it appears that if you want it lined up vertically, then within a Column structure you should specify Alignment->Axis.

Comment: And apparently I cannot reproduce my result above. :(

Answer (score 2):

As stated above you need to have the ImagePadding set the same for every image, you want to use the getMaxPadding function used in this post:  [Programmatically combine 2D contour plots with 1D projections](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/programmatically-combine-2d-contour-plots-with-1d-projections)