# How to calculate a projection of x,y,z data to x any y plane?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, projection

I have a List containing x,y,z data, which I can plot nicely in a ListContourPlot:

```
ListContourPlot[plotData, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 1024]
```

which results in:

[image]

Now I would like to add "projections" of the data in the x and y direction by summing over the z-values in the rows and columns of the plot.

How do I do that? Is there a way of doing this via the List `plotData`?

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13548/9490) close to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this looks quite much what I'd like to see. I still have to dig into the code.

Comment: I formatted the code a bit to make it more readable.  There are probably easier ways to do things, but that is what I came up with at the time.