# How to make a marginal distribution plot using DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

How would you make a marginal distribution plot using DensityPlot? Adapting Sjoerd's answer from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78028/plot-bivariate-data-with-marginals) using `Epilog`, I can plot a slice at a given coordinate (for example, x=0 or y=0) as below:

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)] HermiteH[2, Sqrt[2] x]^2;
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False,
    Epilog -> {Line[Table[{x1, 2.05 + 0.2 f[x1, 0]}, {x1, -2, 2, 0.01}]],
              Line[Table[{ 2.05 + 0.2 f[0, y1], y1}, {y1, -2, 2, 0.01}]] },
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}]
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

But what I'd really like is to plot the column- (row-) integrated values of `DensityPlot` along the x- (y-) axis margins.

The real function of interest for this calculation is expensive, so evaluating only once would be best (i.e., can we use the values of the `DensityPlot`?). Additionally, for this reason, `DensityPlot` is preferred over `ListDensityPlot` for its automatic mesh sampling, since the functions of interest tend to be localized, so a uniform mesh would be wasteful.

Below is an example where plotting along a given slice isn't representative of the marginal distribution:

[image]

and the marginal plots (in red and blue, taken along the light dashed lines) just evaluate to zero.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13479/9490).

Comment: As to your main problem, that the function `f[x,y]` is *expensive* to compute, and you don't want to have to keep recalling it for the density plot and the 1D plots, you have two choices.  First, you could use [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) via `f[x_, y_] := f[x,y] = <expensive computation>`.  Alternatively you could precompute the density as a matrix of values and call `ListDensityPlot` on it.

Comment: @JasonB., great suggestion. ``ListDensityPlot`` is ~3x slower for similar resolution, which I chalked up to the adaptive mesh of ``DensityPlot``, which I'd like to keep. Do you know how to extract the data (i.e., the (x,y,z) coordinates) underlying ``DensityPlot``? If so, memoization would work really well in combination with @kglr 's answer below.

Comment: do you have access to the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, xMargin, yMargin, ppX, ppY]

f[x_, y_] := Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)] HermiteH[2, Sqrt[2] x]^2

xMargin[x_] = Integrate[f[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}];

yMargin[y_] = Integrate[f[x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

xrange = {-3, 3};

yrange = {-2, 2};

scale = 1/4/Pi;

gap = 0.05;

dp = DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {y, yrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, 
       PlotRange -> All]
```

We can construct appropriately translated margins using `ParametricPlot`:

```
ppY = ParametricPlot[{xrange[[1]] - gap - scale v yMargin[y], y},
     {y, yrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, {v, 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False];

ppX = ParametricPlot[{x, yrange[[1]] - gap - scale v xMargin[x] },
   {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False];
```

and combine them with `dp` using `Show`:

```
Show[ppY, ppX, dp, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

To show the marginal plots on top and right frames:

```
ppY2 = ParametricPlot[{xrange[[2]] + gap + scale v yMargin[y], y}, 
    {y, yrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False];

ppX2 = ParametricPlot[{x, yrange[[2]] + gap + scale v xMargin[x]}, 
    {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False];

Show[ppY2, ppX2, dp, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

To put the marginal plots outside the frame, we can use `Inset` + `Epilog`:

```
insetY = Inset[#, {xrange[[2]] (1 + gap), yrange[[2]]},
   {Left, Top}, Scaled[1]] & @ ppY2;

insetX = Inset[#, {xrange[[2]], yrange[[2]] (1 + gap)}, 
   {Right, Bottom}, Scaled[1]] & @ ppX2;

Show[dp, Epilog -> {insetX, insetY}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.02], Scaled[.1]}, {Scaled[.02], Scaled[.1]}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can `Plot` the functions `xMargin` and `yMargin` and use `GeometricTransformation` with appropriate transformation functions position them and `Show` the transformed graphics objects with `dp`:

```
ClearAll[transform, tFX, tFY]
transform[tf_] := Graphics[#[[1]] /. 
     ll : (_Line | _Polygon) :> GeometricTransformation[ll, tf]] &;

tFY = TranslationTransform[{-gap, xrange[[1]]}]@*
   RotationTransform[Pi/2, {xrange[[1]], 0}];

tFX = TranslationTransform[{0, yrange[[1]] - gap}]@*
   ScalingTransform[{1, -1}];

pltY = Plot[scale yMargin[y], {y, yrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, 
   Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False];
pltX = Plot[scale  xMargin[x], {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, 
   Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> Blue, Axes -> False];

Show[transform[tFY]@pltY, transform[tFX]@pltX, dp, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

To show the marginal plots on top and right frames use the transformations `tFX2` and `tFY2`:

```
tFY2 = TranslationTransform[{gap, xrange[[1]]}]@*
   RotationTransform[-Pi/2, {xrange[[2]], 0}];

tFX2 = TranslationTransform[{0, yrange[[2]] + gap}];

Show[transform[tFY2] @ pltY, transform[tFX2] @ pltX, dp, PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach to get the marginal plots: Use `Plot3D` to plot `f` with equally spaced mesh lines in x and y directions and extract the coordinates of mesh lines.

```
ndivs = 50;
{meshx, meshy} = Subdivide[#[[1]], #[[2]], ndivs] & /@ {xrange, yrange};

coords = Plot3D[f[x, y],
    {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {y, yrange[[1]],  yrange[[2]]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {meshx, meshy}, PlotStyle -> None][[1, 1]];
```

Group `coords` by the first and second coordinates and construct two `WeightedData` objects and plot them using `SnoothHistogram`:

```
bw = .01;
{wDx, wDy} = Table[Apply[WeightedData] @ Transpose @ KeyValueMap[List] @
      KeySort @ GroupBy[coords, Round[#[[i]], bw] & -> Last, Mean], {i, 2}];

{sHx, sHy} = {SmoothHistogram[wDx, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
    Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300], 
   SmoothHistogram[wDy, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300]};

Row[{sHx, sHy}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, `Plot` the `PDF` of `SmoothKernelDistribution` of `wDx` and `wDy`:

```
{sKDx, sKDy} = SmoothKernelDistribution /@ {wDx, wDy};

{sHx2, sHy2} = {Plot[PDF[sKDx]@x, {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300], 
   Plot[PDF[sKDy]@y, {y, xrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300]};

Row[{sHx2, sHy2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Processing `DensityPlot` output to get `{x,y,z}` coordinates (where `z` is scaled to the unit interval:

```
dp = DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
coordsFromDP = Join[dp[[1, 1]], List /@ dp[[1, 3, 2, All, 1]], 2];
```

Except for the scale of the `z` coordinate `ListPlot3D` of `coordsFromDP` is "close" to the `Plot3D` output:

```
Row @ {Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotRange -> All], ListPlot3D[coordsFromDP, ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image]

We process `coordsFromDP` the same way we did for `coords` above (except for a larger bin width):

```
bw = .02;
{wDx2, wDy2} = Table[Apply[WeightedData] @ Transpose @ KeyValueMap[List] @
      KeySort@GroupBy[coordsFromDP, Round[#[[i]], bw] & -> Last,  Mean], {i, 2}];

{sHx2, sHy2} = {SmoothHistogram[wDx2, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
    Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300], 
   SmoothHistogram[wDy2, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300]};

Row[{sHx2, sHy2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is really beautiful! Unfortunately, the real function I'm interested takes quite a long time to evaluate. Do you know a way of using the data within ``dp`` to generate ``pltX`` and ``pltY``? If so, that would plug right into your ``GeometricTransformation`` positioning/formatting approach and fully solve my problem!!

Comment: @Jaffe42, I updated with an alternative approach using `Plot3D` output to generate the marginal plots.

Comment: Wow, this is amazingly comprehensive. Completely solved the problem from all angles. Thank you so much!