# Distribution above pointplot

Tags: plotting, histograms

This is my first question here, so I'm sorry if I do something wrong.
Also I'm fairly new to *Mathematica* (using 8). I've used it about 2 months. Only 2 weeks intensive. The rest was about `NDSolve` most of the time to be honest.

I have some results (approx. $100,000$) which I want to represent as a `ListPlot`.
I can generate a `SmoothHistogram` which gives me the distribution of the points.

What I now want to do is something like this:

[image: sample plot]

I tried using `Epilog -> Inset[plot,{0,20},{0,0}]`.
But I can't get the alignment fixed.

I used following code:

Definition of subplot.

```
    distriW = 
  SmoothHistogram[data[[All, 1]], Automatic, "PDF", 
   PlotRange -> {{-22, 20}, {0, 0.75}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   AspectRatio -> 2/9, Axes -> {True, False}, AxesOrigin -> {-20, 0}];
```

Code for the entire plot

```
 Show[ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[1]}, AxesOrigin -> {-20, 0}, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[distriW, {0, 20}, {0, 0}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 40}}, 
  Prolog -> {Directive[lijnen], vert, hori}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameTicks -> Automatic]]
```

Result:

[image: distribution]

As you can see the alignment isn't great in my opinion.
Furthermore, I can get the ticks for the small (sub-)axis right but I need to change the position a little bit.
I have no idea how to do this.
I can find the rotated part myself once I know how to fix this.

Comment: I think you should be able to adapt the solution here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2984/69

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object?rq=1 might help too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have some fun with it for the rest of the evening. Sorry about asking a very similar thing. Still having trouble coming up with the right keywords.