# two histograms ratio

Tags: histograms, plotting

I have two histograms and using listplot to draw both. Now, I want to draw a second plot, below the first, with the ratio of each bin. Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks.

This is the code I'm using to draw the histograms:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

dadosGtop = Import["Gtop_PR.dat", "table"];

costhbGtop = Table[dadosGtop[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, Length[dadosGtop]}];

costhleGtop = Table[dadosGtop[[i]][[2]], {i, 1, Length[dadosGtop]}];


histPlot[data_, bins_, origin_, color_, label_, title_, nome_] := 
  Module[{countBorder1 = 
     Partition[Riffle[Riffle[#1, #1[[2 ;;]]], Riffle[#2, #2]], 2] & @@
       HistogramList[data[[1]], bins], 
    countBorder2 = 
     Partition[Riffle[Riffle[#1, #1[[2 ;;]]], Riffle[#2, #2]], 2] & @@
       HistogramList[data[[2]], bins],
    },
   ListLinePlot[{countBorder1, countBorder2}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {{color[[1]]}, {color[[2]], Dashed}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {Style[label[[1]], 14, Bold], 
      Style[label[[2]], 14, Bold]}, AxesOrigin -> origin, 
    LegendPosition -> {0.65, 0.1}, LegendSize -> 1, 
    LegendShadow -> None, 
    PlotLegend -> {Style[nome[[1]], 12, Bold], 
      Style[nome[[2]], 12, Bold]}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[title, Black, 14, Bold], 
    TicksStyle -> {16, Bold}, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.6]]];

histPlot[{costhbGtop, costhneGtop}, {-1, 1, 0.1}, {-1, 0}, {Green, Blue}, {"\[Eta]", 
  "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(dN\), \(d\[Eta]\)]\)"}, "Pseudorapidity of b", \
{"b", "ne"}]
```

Here is a data sample:

```
dadosGtop={
   {-0.68, 0.536, 0.316}, {-0.394, 0.187, 0.287}, {-0.874, 0.753, 0.474},
   {-0.202, 0.18, 0.066}, {-0.267,  0.894, -0.077}, {0.126, -0.144, -0.063},
   {0.952,  0.63, -0.953}, {0.671, 0.073, -0.84}, {-0.344,  0.72, -0.024},
   {0.824, -0.205, -0.741}, {0.718, -0.793, -0.268}, {-0.423, 0.568, -0.204},
   {-0.192, -0.096, 0.357}, {-0.03,   0.865, -0.629}, {-0.784, 0.39, 0.588},
   {0.98, 0.59, -0.953},   {-0.97,  0.682, 0.653}, {-0.654, 0.907, -0.201},
   {-0.35,   0.712, -0.176}, {-0.929, 0.654, 0.48}, {-0.479, 0.826, 0.099},
   {-0.54, 0.785,-0.724}, {-0.812, 0.818,-0.069}, {-0.988, -0.083, 0.89},
   {-0.559, 0.976,-0.188}, {0.748, 0.211,-0.994}, {0.507, -0.527,-0.266},
   {0.776, -0.025,-0.964}
   }
```

Comment: Hello, can You show us data You are working with ot at least form of the data?

Comment: Sorry, I was going to post the code but there is characters limit! I'm using simple raw data from some file.

Comment: just added the code in the question

Comment: Could You provide a data sample?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: I think I saw something like what you are describing in [VLC's answer to question 2984.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3675/121)

Comment: 1) what version of *Mathematica* are you working on? 2) is `costhneGtop` <-> `costhleGtop` a typo?

Comment: Mathematica 8. Its not a typo. They two different variables. THanks for the support. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 3):

What would be the ratio for `n/0` or `0/0`. You can set easily in definition below:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f[0, 0] := 0;
f[_, 0] := 0;
f[x_, y_] := x/y;
```

If you want to stick with your `Module`, use `Column` as george2079 has said. Divisions are simply:

```
f[counts1, counts2]
```

I find following version a little more compact but the choice is yours.

```
data = {{-0.68, 0.536, 0.316}, {-0.394, 0.187, 0.287}, {-0.874, 0.753, 0.474}, 
        {-0.202, 0.18, 0.066}, {-0.267, 0.894, -0.077}, {0.126, -0.144, -0.063}, 
        {0.952, 0.63, -0.953},  {0.671, 0.073, -0.84}, {-0.344, 0.72, -0.024}, 
        {0.824, -0.205, -0.741}, {0.718, -0.793, -0.268}, {-0.423, 0.568, -0.204}, 
        {-0.192, -0.096, 0.357}, {-0.03, 0.865, -0.629}, {-0.784, 0.39, 0.588},
        {0.98, 0.59, -0.953}, {-0.97, 0.682, 0.653}, {-0.654,0.907, -0.201}, 
        {-0.35, 0.712, -0.176}, {-0.929, 0.654, 0.48}, {-0.479, 0.826, 0.099}, 
        {-0.54, 0.785, -0.724}, {-0.812, 0.818, -0.069}, {-0.988, -0.083, 0.89}, 
        {-0.559, 0.976, -0.188}, {0.748, 0.211, -0.994}, {0.507, -0.527, -0.266}, 
        {0.776, -0.025, -0.964}};

bg = data[[;; , 1]];
nl = data[[;; , 2]];

Module[{d, r, dat},
       d = BinCounts[#, {-1.1, 1.1, .1}] & /@ {bg, nl};
       r = Range[-1, 1, .1] /. n_Real :> {n, n};
       dat = Flatten[Transpose /@ Transpose[{r, Partition[#, 2, 1]}], 1
                    ] & /@ (d~Join~{f @@ d});

       With[{opts = Sequence[Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
                             ImagePadding -> 15, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.1]
            },
            Column[
                   ListLinePlot[##, opts] & @@@ {
                                   {dat[[;; 2]], PlotStyle -> {{Green}, {Dashed, Blue}}},
                                   {Last@dat}}

                  ]
           ]
       ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the ratio plot:

```
ListLinePlot[ 
   MapThread[{#1[[1]], If[#2[[2]] != 0 ,  #1[[2]]/#2[[2]], 0 ]} &,
     {countBorder1 ,   countBorder2 }] ]
```

A simple way to put the plots together is to use GraphicsColumn[{plot1,plot2}]

Comment: Ok, many thanks. I'll try it.