# Align a plot with other rotated plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

i'm plotting two plots one of them is rotated 90º and has no axes labels, so my problem is that when i plot them together in a row the alignment options bottom top align the top to top or bottom to bottom bouncing box of the plots but i want to align the frame boxes of the plot which contain the same plot ranges.

here is my example

```
xticks = Table[{n, Rotate[ToString[n], -40 Degree]}, {n, 0, 10, 1}];
xticks1 = Table[{n, Rotate[ToString[n], 50 Degree]}, {n, 0, 10, 1}];
```

the 1st plot

```
Zoom := Plot[z, {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["time/\[Tau]", 18, Italic]], 
    Text[Style["Position/\[Lambda]", 18, Italic]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0014], Blue}}, 
  FrameStyle -> {{Thickness[0.009], 
     Thickness[0.009]}, {Thickness[0.009], Thickness[0.009]}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
  FrameTicks -> {{xticks1, None}, {{0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}, None}},
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]
```

the rotate plot

```
RotateFit := 
 Rotate[Plot[-0.1 y*y, {y, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False , 
   FrameLabel -> {Text[Style[" ", 18, Italic]],}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, -9}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.014], Orange}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Thickness[0.009], 
      Thickness[0.009]}, {Thickness[0.009], Thickness[0.009]}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], AspectRatio -> 0.4, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{6, 4, 2}, None}, {xticks, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> {278, Automatic}], Pi/2]
```

and then plot them together

```
GraphicsRow[{Zoom, RotateFit}, Spacings -> -188, Alignment -> Top, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

then this is what i get 
[image]

So is there a way to do the frames the same size and then align them, as you can see the rotated one has different frame lines width even when i set thickness to be equal in both frames, they should look something like this which i made in origin 
[image]

Comment: I suggest looking at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2984/69 -- it does similar things.