# How to change frame size, while maintaining ImageSize?

Tags: style, alignment, plot-themes

I'm trying to come up with a MWE:

```
anyData = Range[10];
Column@Table[ListLinePlot[n*anyData, Frame -> True], {n, {-1, 1}}]
```

The lateral size of the plotframe varies, depended on the y-frame-label/ticks. In the example below this is due to the use of negative values, but in general any difference in ticksnumbers and labeling could cause this.

### My question:

Is there a way to get both of the plotframes **equal in size** and **aligned**?
Unfortunately, I'm aware that this might end in the consequence of unequal overall imagesizes. But maybe one could add some blank regions by `Padding` or so... I hope for some possible solutions.

Thanks for your try!!

[image]

Comment: You tried increasing  `ImagePadding`?

Comment: Yes I tried. It might work for some plots, but one has to adjust that manually, right? Not really, what I was hoping for. How can I control, that both framesizes are exactly equal?

Comment: Setting `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` identical for two plots doesn't make the plot content aligned and identical size?

Comment: @BlacKow  The issue is that the tick labels occupy a variable amount of space, depending on their values.  Of course, with a bit of work that size can be determined and accounted for.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - but it looks like it might work (from the first glimpse)... This definitly works. Didn't find a mistake so far! :D

Comment: @BlacKow interesting idea! I never came up with that. So it seems, that `ImagePadding` is variable when not fixed?

Comment: @BlacKow - Do you want to write an answer I can accept? Could you also shortly explain, why this works?? Thx!

Comment: Many related: [1337](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13373/89), [4059](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4059/89), [1025](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102540/89), [66350](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66350/89), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to **BlacKow** I just found out that:

> "[ImagePadding](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html#) is defined within ImageSize"

and

> "ImageMargins is defined outside of ImageSize"

```
anyData = Range[10];
pad = 40;
l1 = ListLinePlot[-1*anyData, Frame -> True, 
       ImagePadding -> {{pad, 1}, {1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300];
l2 = ListLinePlot[10000*anyData, Frame -> True, 
       ImagePadding -> {{pad, 1}, {1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300];
Column@{l1, l2}
```

perfectly works!!

[image]