# Match axes lengths of two plots?

Tags: plotting, style

Consider the two plots

```
{
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 100}, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {All, None}}, AspectRatio -> 5/16, 
  ImageSize -> {600, Automatic}]
 ,
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 100}, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {All, None}}, AspectRatio -> 5/16, 
  ImageSize -> {600, Automatic}]
 }
```

> [image]

I would like both of them to appear perfectly one above the other with exactly the same x-axis lengths, starting and ending at the same x-axis-pixel locations respectively on my screen. How can I do this?

Comment: This? [Align Plots with Each Other](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/AlignPlotsWithEachOther.html)

Comment: Also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112598/how-to-change-frame-size-while-maintaining-imagesize/112611#112611)

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer `ImagePadding` is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: I just had this need myself (for my thesis), so it was at the top of my head :P