# Display vertical histogram alongside a list plot

Tags: plotting, histograms

Suppose I have some data ranging from `-xRange` to `xRange`:

```
fooData := Table[{i - xRange, RandomReal[]}, {i, 2*xRange-1}];
sampleFoo = Table[fooData, {i, 1, 100}];
```

where `xRange` is some integer. Suppose I want a histogram of the distribution of data at `x = 0`, i.e. at the `xRange`-th element of the list:

```
histData = Histogram[sampleFoo[[All, xRange, 2]], BarOrigin -> Left];
```

When I plot it (in my `init.m` file I set options for plots such that they always show frames instead of axes) I'd like the histogram to be on the left edge of the frame. Instead, this

```
Show[ListPlot[sampleFoo, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1]]], 
    histData]
```

gives me the histogram placed at `x=0`, rather than where I want it to be.

[image: Output image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/how-can-i-make-an-x-y-scatter-plot-with-histograms-next-to-the-x-y-axes) help?

Comment: That is very similar to what I was trying to do, and with a bit of tweaking might actually work just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Will this work for you?

```
SeedRandom[42];
Module[{xmax = 25, n = 100, data, sample, hist, plot}, 
 data := Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {i, Subdivide[-xmax, xmax, 2 xmax]}]; 
 sample = Table[fooData, {i, 1, n}];
 hist =
   Histogram[sample[[All, xmax, 2]], {.2},
     AspectRatio -> 2,
     BarOrigin -> Left,
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}];
 plot = 
   ListLinePlot[sample,
     Axes -> None,
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1],
     Frame -> True,
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}];
 Row[{hist, "  ", plot}]]
```

[image: plot]